# Get user id when registers

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, userid, onesignal

I am getting familiar with the cordova/phonegap sdk for [onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/phonegap--cordova-sdk-api#idsReceivedCallBack). But I don't know how to get the userid when he registers..

I can get all ids:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("my-key",
                         {googleProjectNumber: "my-id"},
                         notificationOpenedCallback);

window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
did = ids.userId;
window.localStorage.setItem("did",ids.userId);
});
```

But I don't know how to get the current user id, or match agains one the ids

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct. Once a user's device connects to OneSignal (Shortly after init is called), your function should be receiving the OneSignal ID and saving it in localstorage.

If it doesn't seem to be working, please try using console.log(ids) to see if the callback is ever executed. You should also look at the logcat output from your device to see if any errors (or logging output) is displayed. Finally, you can use the OneSignal [setLogLevel](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap--cordova-sdk-api#setLogLevel) function to see additional debugging output from logcat.

Comment: Ok! thank you very much

for some reason, I thought that this method returned all de devices!

Comment: Do we have to call the getIds method every time on app launch or can we do it just once and store the playerid in localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

This should surely work!

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("my-key",
                     {googleProjectNumber: "my-id"},
                     notificationOpenedCallback);

window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
playerId = ids.userId;
console.log('my playerId is:' playerId);
window.localStorage.setItem("playerId",ids.userId);
});
```